# how can I get the yes command to force overwrite and to do so with new lines?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, cp, bsd

I would like `cp` to prompt before overwriting so I am using `-i`.

(I might sometimes use an alias for `cp`, or similar, so `cp` always occurs with `-i`).

I may want to say overwrite all.  I know that's the default but since i'm using `-i` I don't see that.

I want to easily be able to make it do 'yes' to all, or 'no' to all.

I am not asking how to bypass an alias, I want the `-i`.

Here is my attempt at forcing yes, given `-i`.

```
~$ mkdir test1
~$ cd test1
~/test1$ mkdir smalls
~/test1$ touch a.a
~/test1$ touch b.b
~/test1$ cp -i ?.? smalls
~/test1$ cp -i ?.? smalls
overwrite smalls/a.a? (y/n [n]) y
overwrite smalls/b.b? (y/n [n]) y
~/test1$ yes|cp -i ?.? smalls
overwrite smalls/a.a? (y/n [n]) overwrite smalls/b.b? (y/n [n]) ~/test1$ 
~/test1$ 
~/test1$ yes ''|cp -i ?.? smalls
overwrite smalls/a.a? (y/n [n]) not overwritten
overwrite smalls/b.b? (y/n [n]) not overwritten
~/test1$
```

So I manage to force 'y' to all but then I don't get new lines.

When I try `yes ''|`  then it doesn't send a yes.

I'd also like to be able to pass an 'n'/'no' too.

And I may have many files so I'm not looking to manually type <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>n</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> for each file.

I don't mind a solution that doesn't involve the `yes` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as easy as it may seem.

#### Analysis

When running `cp -i` and answering it prompts interactively, the newline you get after typing <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> comes from the line discipline. The line discipline echoes `y` and the newline.

You can observe this mechanism by running sole `cat` in a terminal. When `cat` awaits input, you can type a long line and even erase characters (with <kbd>Backspace</kbd>) or the whole line (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>); everything you see is handled by the line discipline, `cat` just sits there without any input. Only when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>), `cat` gets the line and prints it. The newline after what you typed is from the line discipline, the newline after what `cat` printed is from `cat`.

Or you can type something and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to send it to `cat` without a newline. Then there will be no newline after what you typed and no newline after what `cat` printed.

Similarly, when prompted by `cp -i`, you can interactively type <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (why twice? [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177651/108618)), `cp` will accept `y` and you will see `y` echoed by the line discipline, but no newline (because you did not type one). `cp` itself does not print a newline here. Normally (i.e. when you do type <kbd>Enter</kbd>) what you see looks right (i.e. with newlines in the right places) because of the line discipline. We can say `cp` expects a line discipline that injects newline characters where appropriate and thus makes the output look nice.

The point is *there is* a line discipline between your keyboard and `cp -i`, it echoes what you type, including a newline upon <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In your `yes | cp -i …`, `cp` gets input almost as if you typed <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> via a line discipline, but this time there is nothing like a line discipline that would echo what enters `cp`. This is the reason you observed no newlines (and no `y` characters).

In the case of `yes '' | cp -i …`, the newlines after `not overwritten` were actually printed by `cp`. What's missing is a newline before each `not overwritten`. Without `yes`, if you just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in response to the prompt, you would see `not overwritten` in a separate line.

---

#### Towards solution

To get what you want, you need something that echoes the input that goes into `cp`. At first glance it seems it may be an actual line discipline (few ideas here: [*How to trick a command into thinking its output is going to a terminal*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249723/108618); note we don't want to trick `cp`, we want a "side effect" of having a terminal) or `tee` between `yes` and `cp`, like this:

```
# both flawed
yes | socat STDIO EXEC:'cp -i …',pty
yes | tee >/dev/tty | cp -i …
```

The above will not work well because `yes` generates its output immediately and as much as possible, it's like a user who mashes <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> no matter if prompted or not. Echoing this makes the output look way worse than what you posted in the question.

Even if you knew in advance you needed just one <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, using `echo y` instead of `yes` would also not work well, because most likely the input would be seen and printed (by the added line discipline or by `tee`) before `cp` prints its prompt.

---

#### Solution

A proper solution is to run `cp -i …` with additional pty, but only give it input when prompted. `expect(1)` can do it. This is a quick and dirty `expect` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set str [lindex $argv 0]
spawn -noecho cp -i {*}[lrange "$argv" 1 end]
while 1 {
   expect {
      "overwrite *\\?" { send "$str\r" }
      eof exit
   }
}
```

<sup>Users with localized `cp` should adjust the `"overwrite *\\?"` pattern.</sup>

Be advised I have little experience with `expect`, the script may be sub-optimal or even somewhat flawed. Treat it as a proof of concept. Save the script as `cpx` in a directory in your `$PATH`, make it executable (`chmod +x cpx`) and use like this:

```
cpx y ?.? smalls
# or
cpx n ?.? smalls
```

In practice it may be good to define shell aliases:

```
alias cpy='cpx y'
alias cpn='cpx n'
```

and use them like this:

```
cpy ?.? smalls
# or
cpn ?.? smalls
```

Answer (score -1):

Plenty of ways to bypass the alias to use native `cp`:

- Use the command builtin: `command cp`
- Use the full path of the command: `/bin/cp`
- Add a \ anywhere in the command name, for example: `\cp`
- Quote the command: `"cp"` or `'cp'`

Comment: -1 why on earth are you telling me how to bypass an alias, I very clearly never asked such a thing at all

Comment: I have now added this line `I am not asking how to bypass an alias, I want the -i.` making it even more clear and obvious.

Comment: And if I wanted to ask how to bypass an alias, i'd have asked that, without any of the other stuff, but I didn't.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted a practical solution.

Comment: a solution to the question I asked, whose first line includes the words "I am using -i."

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'yes |' in front of your code.

```
yes | cp -i ?.? smalls
```

Comment: no that's not a solution, the question itself mentions that